# Как прокрутить страницу в Selenium WebDriver C#?

Tags: c#, selenium

Собственно как прокрутить страницу вниз?
Страница Ютуб с видео, нужно прокручивать пока не загрузятся все комментарий(ну или пока не упадет браузер от перегрузки=)
Как это сделать?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18625320/12888024